# How to collide player with obstacles in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am beginner and i am developing a game using cocos2d-x in x-code for ios, and i need to collide my player with obstacle please help me to sort out this.

Comment: Please provide more details, in particular what player and obstacle are, whether you are interested in detecting overlap only or also collision resolve (ie resolving/avoiding overlap). For example, would a rectangle to rectangle intersection suffice to determine contact? If you don't know where to start, google it.

Answer (score 0):

There really needs to be more information to help, here is some documentation: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Chapter_5_-_How_to_Detect_the_Collisions

In essence you will be checking the `bounding box` of each to detect if they intersect somehow.

Or use Box2D.